# turn-based game how switch between 2 players

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coding my first POO project. Could you help to switch from one player to another? I know my code is far from perfect. I think I have all the elements but I have trouble using them. if someone with more experience could help me.  All in JavaScript and for mooving I would like use jQuery.

Currently the code works well, in a main.js file I have a function that defines which begins. I move 3 times the player selected by random and after I should switch between the characters but I can not. Thank's.

Comment: Erm I think you might have forgotten your code

Comment: No I have deleted my code. the are no answer ,so no utility to stay here and I can't delete the Post.

Answer (score 1):

First a remark: using jQuery does not mean you just assign properties to variables that start with `$`. Sometimes programmers using jQuery name their variables like that, but *only* to denote jQuery objects (containing zero or more DOM object references), not just any value.

Now to why your code does not work:

Doing `$compteur--` does not affect `this.compteur`. Those two variables contain primitive values and so changing one has no effect on the other: they live separate lives.

Replace the definition of `$compteur = this.compteur` with the definition of `that` :

```
var that = this;
```

And then replace `$compteur--` with:

```
that.compteur--;
```

Comment: Ok In first Very thanks for your advice. I will try to define var that = this. I use $ before variable becaus it's an advice from khan akademy where john resig work now. so I have think it's good practice. thank for all

Comment: But you are certainly right you must not do it every time

Comment: I'm sorry but that don't work ! maybe it's me, I call switchPlayer() just before switch no ?

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle that demonstrates the issue because your question does not have a call to `switchPlayer`. What doesn't work? A bit more details would helpful. Have you debugged the code? What are the values of the important variables when you make that call multiple times? etc...etc...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to find the solution alone. My initial question specifies that precisely I do not know or call my function switchPlayer(), all the tests I did not work. there must be a problem with $compteur. thank you for your help

Comment: We can of course not guess what the rest of your code looks like (what is `#board`,  ...Etc), and we don't know the game (are there timers? Are moves played automatically? Is there a button to press?), so there is no way we can tell you where to call the function. Anyway, good luck ;-)

Comment: No problem thanks for all ( all my cell are id's board-0 to board-99)